# CSS slash border

Tags: css, sass, border

[image]

As seen in the picture, the background colour is magenta and the button is white.
Right bottom corner of the button is not either rectangular or rounded but kind of slash off.

Can I achieve this using CSS?

Comment: yes, you can do it by CSS

Comment: @NishargShah can you refer me to an example?

Comment: I added an answer, lookout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example with new property `clip-path`.

You can do experiments on https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ site

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 50px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 75%, 75% 100%, 0 100%);
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">
    button
</div>
```